# How to create a display method that relies on two other display methods?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a header/lines type of object (think SalesTable/PurchTable), and on the header I have two calculated display methods, "total qty" and "total invoiced".

I want to add a simple display that says "Fully Invoiced", which is a display method that returns:

`return this.TotalQty() == this.TotalInvoiced();`

The issue is that calls the two display method calculations again, which could be performance hit on ListPages.

Is there a way to make a form method that uses the cached values so I don't have to call extra calculations and I don't have to create a table column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to access the values that have been cached for display methods in code.

You could define the display method on the table and use the [existing caching mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa596691.aspx). You would have to define the other two display methods `totalQty` and `totalInvoiced` on the table, too. Note that this will still result in some unnecessary calls to `totalQty` and `totalInvoiced`.

Another way would be to implement your own caching mechanism in the form by e.g. using a map that holds the RecIds and cache values (see [Caching display methods on a form datasource](https://axology.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/caching-display-methods-on-a-form-datasource/) for an example/tutorial). But if performance is more a theoretical than a practical problem, I would not recommend this approach.

A third option could be to combine the queries in `totalQty` and `totalInvoiced` into one query that is then used by the `fullyInvoiced` display method. This will introduce some redundancy in your code and you would still have to define `fullyInvoiced` on the table to leverage caching. But depending on the queries it could improve performance.

Comment: That's what I figured. I was hoping I could put AutoDec=Yes on the two display method fields, then put a datamethod on the grid itself and maybe set it equal to field1.RealValue==field2.RealValue;